# Is there a cap to your spouse's income?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've read in several posts now that a common way of making money is:

1. Get married
2. Wait/Sleep for 10 consecutive days
3. Take the 1k Septims from your spouse

I understand that spouses have a cumulative income of 100 Septims per day.  Is the 10 days recommendation made because that's the cap for accumulation?  Or is it just to have a nice round number of 1k?

Is there *any* upper limit to how much gold your spouse will give you, or does it just build up to infinity?  If I am away from home for a year, can I still get 36,500 Septims from her?  How about two years?  Ten?

Comment: Lots of question about spouse's income, how much materialism in Skyrim. :)

Comment: no, spousal income accumulates.  @Drake I think people are just enjoying the idea that spouses in Skyrim actually makes you money rather than cost money :P

Comment: @yz Haha you are right, I love fantasy games. ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A spouse in Skyrim gives 100 Septims a day. There is no limit to their income, it is only tied to the time passed.

10 days = 1000 Septims is just a good round figure. There is no cap or limitations to monetary income from your spouse, other than the 100 Septims a day limit,which does have an exception...

For example, my wife Ysolda from Whiterun sells everything, has 772 Septims and when I buy something from her I get a portion back in addition to the 100 Septims.

Now if they only let you pass the time in weeks... :)